# asp:FileUpload having null on submit

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I'm trying to have a `asp:FileUpload` element so I can upload images to a folder through my website. The problem is that whenever I submit the form, this element is null, meaning it contains no file.

This is my code:

```
HTML:

<asp:FileUpload id="FileUploadControl" runat="server" />



C#:

// .. Some other form validation codes (not related to the FileUpload)
if (FileUploadControl.HasFile) // .HasFile always = false
{
    string path = "~/MSImages/", mappath = Server.MapPath(path);
    try
    {
        if (FileUploadControl.PostedFile.ContentType.StartsWith("image/", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists(mappath))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(mappath);
            string filename = imgext + Request.QueryString["id"];
            FileUploadControl.SaveAs(mappath + filename);
        }
    }
    catch { }
}
```

What am I doing wrong that it's not working?

Comment: My first instinct is that there's some kind of ViewState or PageLoad event interfering. Without more from your example it will be difficult to pinpoint the problem. Is the FileUpload control in a repeater or other databound control, for example?

Comment: I figured what the problem is. It was caused because the whole page was inside a `<asp:UpdatePanel>` tags. Although, I'd like to keep the UpdatePanel, so if you know how to solve it, I'll be glad to know.

Comment: Update Panels don't play nicely with a few controls. Found this thread which may be of help: http://forums.asp.net/t/1105208.aspx?File+Upload+Control+is+not+working+in+Update+Panel

Answer (score 0):

Probably the most common cause is lack of `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in the definition of your `form`.